# JQuery input messages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with inputs. The first input needs to be filled out before the second input.

If the user clicks on input 2 first they get a message saying to fill the other input first. Now I want to make it so that after the message pops up, if the user then fills out input one the message disappears.

**[My codepen](https://codepen.io/anon_guy/pen/WXgZQw)**.

I tried adding an onchange function but that doesn't seem to work.

```js
$('body').on('focus', '.clickable', function() {
  if (!$('.look').val().length) {
    $(this).siblings('p').text('Please select Type first')
  }
});
$('body').on('change', '.look', function() {
  if ($('.look').val().length) {
    $(this).siblings('p').text('')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    Input-1:<br>
    <input type="text" name="first" id="one" class="look"><br> Input-2:
    <br>
    <input class="clickable" type="text" name="second" id="two">
    <p class="warning"></p>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

on change called when you leave the input, your code works when leaving the input, also you can change the "on change" by keyup to see the changes whitout leaving the input

```
codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QOzKwQ
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use keyup as your event instead of change. Change needs to wait for you to click away from the input (blur).

```
$( 'body').on('focus','.clickable',function() {
  if (!$('.look').val().length) {
    $(this).siblings('p').text('Please select Type first')
  }
});
$( 'body').on('keyup','.look',function() {
    if ($('.look').val().length) {
      $(this).siblings('p').text('')
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .on("change keyup paste"...)
to detect immediate changes to the text-field

```
$( 'body').on('focus','.clickable',function() {
    $('.look').on("change keyup paste", function(){
        $(this).siblings('p').text('')
    });

    if (!$('.look').val().length) {
        $(this).siblings('p').text('Please select Type first')
    }
});
$( 'body').on('change','.look',function() {
    if ($('.look').val().length) {
        $(this).siblings('p').text('')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to change your approach but you could try disabling the field so they can't click it and then enable it once input 1 has been filled?

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <div>
        Input-1:<br>
        <input type="text" name="first" id="one" class="look"><br>
        Input-2:<br>
        <input class="clickable" type="text" name="second" id="two" >
        <p class="warning"></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

The **JS:**

```
document.getElementById("two").disabled = true;

var dis1 = document.getElementById("one");
dis1.onchange = function () {
    if (this.value != "" || this.value.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("two").disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be more efficient if you track the user input using `input` event like :

```
$('body').on('input', '.look', function() {
  if ($('.look').val().length) {
    $(this).siblings('p').text('')
  }
});
```

Snippet:

```js
$('body').on('focus', '.clickable', function() {
  if (!$('.look').val().length) {
    $(this).siblings('p').text('Please fill the first input.')
  }
});
$('body').on('input', '.look', function() {
  if ($('.look').val().length) {
    $(this).siblings('p').text('')
  }
});
```

```css
.warning {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div>
    Input-1:<br>
    <input type="text" name="first" id="one" class="look"><br> Input-2:
    <br>
    <input class="clickable" type="text" name="second" id="two">
    <p class="warning"></p>
  </div>

</form>
```